# Data printed twice in first iteration

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-excel

I'm using laravel blade. I try to print array of data as a column in a table. then, I put a conditional expression inside the loop to avoid printing the same value in the same column. After that my data printed twice in the first iteration.Here is the code

```
    {{ $prevKomponen = null }}
    {{ $prevKegiatan = null }}
    @foreach($data as $key => $value)
        <tr>

            @if ($prevKomponen != $value['komponen'])

                <td>{{ $value['komponen'] }}***</td>  

            @else

                <td>-------</td>

            @endif    

            {{ $prevKomponen = $value['komponen'] }}

            <td>{{$value['kegiatan']}}</td>
            <td>{{$value['subkegiatan']}}</td>
            <td>{{$value['rincian']}}</td>
            <td>{{$value['jumlah']}}</td>
            <td>{{$value['harga']}}</td>
            <td>{{$value['total_harga']}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

And here is the result. Data in column 1 is also printed in column 2

[image]

Any help  to address this problem ?

Comment: Maybe because your affectation is also returning the value so it's printed ... Why are you doing ``{{ $prevKomponen = $value['komponen'] }}`` ?

Comment: @Ko2r I need it to be a comparison for data in the next row. If the value of "komponen" in the next row is the same as previous row, then do not print it

Comment: How you want result to be? Can you provide sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be caused by https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data. It says
"You may display data passed to your Blade views by wrapping the variable in curly braces".

So, when you hit these line:

```
{{ $prevKomponen = $value['komponen'] }}
```

It will display as output.

But, if you want to ignore it, you can add '@' symbol, just like this:

```
@{{ $prevKomponen = $value['komponen'] }}
```

'@' symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should remain untouched. Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: how about using php tag <?php ?> instead of {{ }} ? or move your code {{ $prevKomponen = $value['komponen'] }} into line before endforeach loop?

Comment: moving ` {{ $prevKomponen = $value['komponen'] }}` right before @endforeach solve the problem.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have missing a **td**, try this snipet in your **if** condition

```
@if ($prevKomponen != $value['komponen'])

         <td>{{ $value['komponen'] }}***</td>  

        @else

                <td>-------</td>

       @endif    

          <td>{{ $prevKomponen = $value['komponen'] }}</td>
```

Comment: `{{ $prevKomponen = $value['komponen'] }}`  is not meant to be displayed. This is only to assign value to `$prevKomponen`